# How to select upvote arrow for a comment in Stack Exchange using Windows 8 tablet?

Tags: support, tablets, windows-8

I am unable to select the upvote arrow for a comment on Stack Exchange sites using my Windows 8 Surface tablet. It seems that there is no equivalent to mouseover via a tablet. Is this currently possible?

Comment: more to do with touchscreen devices in general, is being discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95446/detect-mobile-browsers-and-change-hover-behavior-accordingly)

Comment: Yeah, this seems more suited to meta...

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the link. Nice to have this question here to be able to go there and see that a fix is in the works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the mobile view with the link at the bottom of the page.

On a phone (touchscreen):

[image]

The only thing it's really missing is the share link...